# call function using onclick inside string for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a table depending on the result of a function for then append in a div like this:

```
    let result = document.getElementById("result");
    consultCities();
    
    function consultCities (){
        consultarAPI(username, password, "cities")
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.login !== "Fail"){
                let table = "";
                let thead = "";
                let tbody = "";
    
                thead += `<tr>
                            <th>Citie</th>
                            <th>Dane</th>
                            <th>Look Institution</th>
                          </tr>`
                for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length;  i += 1 ){
    
                    tbody += `<tr>
                                    <td>${response.data[i].name}</td>
                                    <td>${response.data[i].dane}</td>
                                    <td><button type="button" id="ver" onclick="${consultInstitutions(response.data[i].dane)}">Ver</button></td>
                               </tr>`
                }
    
                table += `<table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                ${thead}
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                ${tbody}
                            </tbody>
                          </table>`
    
                result.innerHTML = table;
            }else{
                alert("El Usuario no existe o la opción no existe");
            }
        });
    }

function consultInstitutions(codCity){
    console.log(codCity);
}
```

The problem is the onclick trigger runs automatically although I don't click in any button, my question is there a best way that I can set onclick a button for a string?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that you are running the function immediately by placing it within `${}`. Instead you just want to place the variable within the `${}`.

```js
onclick="consultInstitutions(${response.data[i].dane})"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did in that way, but now it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: consultInstitutions is not defined"

Comment: From your comment, it looks like a spelling error of consultInstitutions. However, if not, this does assume that this javascript file is linked to your html file. If not, you can't call that function from onclick without embedding it into the html page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative version of your script. I took the liberty of inventing some test data in order to make it an MCVE.

```js
const D={login:"OK",data:[
 {name:"Rome",dane:"Gio"}, {name:"Kiev",dane:"Ivan"}, {name:"Paris",dane:"Lorraine"}, {name:"Ohio",dane:"Matt"}, {name:"Minsk",dane:"Sergey"}]},
  tbl = document.getElementById("result");
tbl.innerHTML=makeTable(D);
tbl.onclick=ev=>{
 if(ev.target.tagName==="BUTTON")
  console.log(ev.target.closest("td").previousElementSibling.textContent)
}

function makeTable(resp){
  if(resp.login !== "Fail")
  return `<table class="table table-bordered"><thead><tr><th>Citie</th><th>Dane</th><th>Look Institution</th></tr></thead><tbody>`
 + resp.data.map(r=>
  `<tr><td>${r.name}</td><td>${r.dane}</td><td><button type="button">Ver</button></td></tr>`).join("\n")
 + "</tbody></table>";
else
  alert("El Usuario no existe o la opción no existe");
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

I used a delegated attachment handling: The click event is listened to by the `<table>` element but the action only happens if the clicked element (`ev.target`) happens to be a "BUTTON". In that case the function looks for the text content of the previous `<TD>` element and `cinsole.log()`s it. Doing it this way I can keep the HTML-template strings in my markup generator function `makeTable()` very simple.